# Raphael JS Flipping Image

Tags: javascript, raphael, transform

I have the following code:

```
image1Rect.animate({
    transform: "S-0.025,1"
}, 1000, 'easeOut', function () {
    image1Rect.hide();
    image1Ref.show();
    image1Ref.scale(0.025, 1);
    image1Ref.animate({
        transform: "S1,1"
    }, 1000, 'easeOut');
});
```

where I am trying to reduce X scale of `image1Rect` to `0.025` and then when that is done increase the scale X of `image1Ref` from `0.025` to `1`. I am trying to do this using appended transforms but since that did not work for me I had to use deprecated function scale on `image1Ref` to first reduce its scale X to `0.025`.

I would ideally like to do this using appended transforms, could you please help me out?

Comment: im not clear on what the problem is and what "appended transforms" have to do with "flipping image"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is caused by the negative integer in

```
transform: "S-0.025,1"
```

Negative integers cause the image to flip in that axis.

use
transform: "S0.025,1"

Answer (score 0):

Try using the matrix as part of the transform:

```
var R = this.paper;
```

*loop through paths*

```
R.path(blah blah).attr(blah blah).transform("m1,0,0,-1,0,0");
```

*end loop*

---

"m" stands for matrix, and the 4th place "-1" represents the image flip. "1" in that place  - (the y-axis place) would be a normal 'as-the-path' dictates, view. Keep in mind you will no longer see your image on the screen, because it has been redrawn well above the containing div. As far as I can tell, it uses the top edge of the div as its pivot.

As an aside, the other places represent some form of 'skew' for the image, which is not interesting if all you want to do is flip it.

To see my image, I had to locate and zoom above it using the viewBox, like this:

```
R.setViewBox(0,-575,200,200);
```